# Nested structures in C# P/Invoke

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I am trying to call into an unmanaged DLL that has the following structure:

```
typedef struct
    {
      int num_objects;
      ppr_object_type *objects;
    } ppr_object_list_type;
ppr_coordinate_type;

typedef struct
{
  int model_id;
  ppr_coordinate_type position;
  float scale_factor;
  float size;
  ppr_rotation_type rotation;
  int nominal_width;
  int nominal_height;
  float confidence;
  int num_landmarks;
  ppr_landmark_type *landmarks;
} ppr_object_type;

typedef struct
{
  float x;
  float y;
} 

typedef struct
{
  float yaw;
  float pitch;
  float roll;
  ppr_precision_type precision;
} ppr_rotation_type;
```

This is what I am using on the C# side:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ObjectInfo
    {
        public int numObjects;
        public ObjectType objListPointer;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ObjectType
    {
        int model_id;
        Coordinate position;
        float scale_factor;
        float size;
        Rotation rotation;
        int nominal_width;
        int nominal_height;
        float confidence;
        int num_landmarks;
        IntPtr landmarks;

    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Coordinate
    {
        float x;
        float y;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Rotation
    {
        float yaw;
        float pitch;
        float roll;
        int precision;
    }
```

The call I am making is specified like this:

```
ppr_error_type ppr_detect_objects (ppr_context_type context,
                                   ppr_image_type image,
                                   ppr_object_list_type *object_list);
```

My C# call looks like this:

```
ObjectInfo info = new ObjectInfo();
int objOK = ppr_detect_objects(context, imagePtr, ref info);
```

I know that the ppr_object_list_type is expecting to fill in an array of objects.  And I know C# has troubles with arbitray arrays of nested objects.  I was thinking that the way I am doing it would return just the first one (which is all I care about).

However, when I call it this way "num_objects" is filled in correctly with a value of 1.  The model_id is wrong (looks like a memory address) and everything else is zeros.

Any help is appreciated.  I have done lots of work passing structures to unmanages code, but never anything remotely this complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ppr_object_list_type` contains a *pointer* to a `ppr_object_type`, not an actual `ppr_object_type` value.

You need to change `ObjectInfo` to

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ObjectInfo
{
    public int numObjects;
    public IntPtr objListPointer;
}
```

To access the `ObjectType` values, you'll need to use the methods in the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal_methods.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks.  This was what I was missing.  I did this:  
ObjectType foo = (ObjectType) Marshal.PtrToStructure(objPtr, typeof (ObjectType));

It works now.
ad

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you only care about the first item:

```
public struct ObjectInfo
{
    public int numObjects;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public ObjectType[] objListPointer;
}
```